# New Matrix with new rows formed in 2nd dataframe wrt 1st dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

```
data1 = { 'node1': [1,1,1,2],
     'node2': [2,3,5,4],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1], }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['node1','node2','weight'])

data2 = { 'node1': [1,1,2,3],
     'node2': [4,5,4,5],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1], }
df2= pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['node1','node2','weight'])


Expected Output:

0 0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

I would like to create a matrix with the the 1's in the matrix indicating the new rows formed in the second dataframe. For example- 2 4 is a row which is in both the dataframes so in the matrix we put matrix[2,4]=0 and [4,2]=0 as the relation is bidirectional.

2) 1 4 is a new row in the second dataframe which is not in the 1st dataframe so we put matrix[1,4]=1 and [4,1]=1

3)If a combination doesnt appear like [3,4] in both the dfs then its matrix[3,4]=matrix[4,3]=0

Also since this is a representational dataset and my real dataset is huge therefore sparse representation is **needed**.

Comment: Could you explain a bit how you got a 5x5 sparse?

Comment: This is a small representative dataset of my bigger dataset.I want the code to work on my larger dataset too

Comment: I add tag numpy.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) for `1` values with [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for all `0`:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, 'outer', indicator=True).query("_merge=='left_only'")
print (df)
   node1  node2  weight     _merge
0      1      4       1  left_only
3      3      5       1  left_only

df3 = df.set_index(['node1','node2'])['weight'].unstack().notnull().astype(int)

df3 = df3.mul(df3.T, fill_value=1)

cols = ['node1','node2']
min1 = df1[cols].values.min()
max1 = df1[cols].values.max()
min2 = df2[cols].values.min()
max2 = df2[cols].values.max()


a = range(min(min1,min2), max(max1, max2) + 1)

df3 = df3.reindex(index=a, columns=a).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df3)
   1  2  3  4  5
1  0  0  0  1  0
2  0  0  0  0  0
3  0  0  0  0  1
4  1  0  0  0  0
5  0  0  1  0  0
```

Comment: Sir now I understand the output. Wish OP put that column names of sparse. That clears a lot of doubts

Comment: @jezrael I want the final answer in matrix format so I converted df3 to it.But when I am working on real dataset the matrix has dimension of 100,000X100,000.

Comment: Yes, last use `arr = df3.values`

Comment: Sir for that big data merge is definitely not suggested. It might take days to get the output.

Comment: @Bharath yes I tried that the computer hangs when doing that